# Convert sequential images from bmp to png in ubuntu terminal

Tags: bash, ubuntu, converters

I know I can use the comand convert, but how can I canvert sequential images in the same folder?

I found this to rename them,

```
a=1
for i in *.png; do printf -v new  "rgb%04d.png" ${a}; mv ${i} ${new}; let a=a+1; done
```

I got this but it does not get rid of the old extension,

```
for file in *.bmp; do convert "$file" "$file".png; done
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use parameter expansion with `%`:

```
for file in *.bmp; do convert "$file" "${file%.bmp}".png; done
```

Comment: I would like to add that to use the `convert` command you need to install additional packages. In particular I had to do `sudo apt-get install imagemagick`